# MySQL Value Returns Null After Select

Tags: php, mysql, forms, select

```
if (! empty ( $fname ) && ! empty ( $lname )) {
        $query5 = "select * from " . $db_prefix . "customer_det where (fname = '" . $fname . "' and lname = '" . $lname . "')";
            $result5 = $mysqli->query ( $query5, MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ) or die ( mysql_error () );
    } else {
        $query5 = "select * from " . $db_prefix . "customer_det where phone = '" . $phone . "'";
        $result5 = $mysqli->query ( $query5, MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ) or die ( mysql_error () );

    }
    while ($row=$result5->fetch_assoc) {
        $uid = $row['id'];
            $visits = $row['visits'];
        }
        var_dump($uid);
        var_dump($visits);
            var_dump($result5);
            var_dump($fname);
            var_dump($lname);
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here.  I run both of those queries in the phpMyAdmin SQL query box and it returns a row set.  Then when I run it in PHP, and var_dump the variables, $uid returns NULL as well as $visits.  Here's the var dump:

```
NULL NULL object(mysqli_result)#4 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(34) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(1) ["type"]=> int(0) } string(6) "Wesley" string(6) "Snipes"
```

Any advice would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're calling `fetch_assoc()`, you're forgetting the parentheses:

```
while ($row=$result5->fetch_assoc) {
```

Should be:

```
while ($row=$result5->fetch_assoc()) {
```

Because of this, the loop is never entered and `$uid` and `$visits` aren't being set (so they're still `null`).

Comment: Thank's so much, It's going to be a long day:(

Comment: @user1718270 It's such a small thing, it's easy to skip over it (fresh eyes always help!).